# Using RadioShack relocatable power tap (120V/60Hz) in 230V/50Hz country

Tags: power, mains

I have RadioShack relocatable power tap 34C4.

[image]

It says "max. load 15A 125VAC 60Hz".

We have a 230v/50Hz standard in my country. Will it cause any problems if I just plug it in the 230V/50Hz outlet to power 230V/50Hz devices? What output frequency and voltage will I get? Also, how to calculate max. load/wattage for it, considering it will be used with 230V, and not with 125V, will it be lower?

Comment: Do you believe that there will be enough insulation and clearance for that device to withstand 230V?

Comment: I am complete novice, so I simply do not know

Comment: Well, the rating is as clear as it's written but if I have the choice of using it at my own risk I would probably just do it. But you should really worry about accidentally plug in some 110V only device to it. The sockets in different countries are not compatible for a reason (if they things are not electrically compatible, make sure they can not plug in together, ironically the USB-C people forgot this completely)

Comment: So, you take your petrol car to the fuel pump and fill it full of diesel. No you wouldn't do that would you?

Comment: Make sure it is not the "surge protector" type as that can be damaged by the higher voltage.

Comment: Also, just FYI, the Philippines uses 220V 60 Hz *AND* uses the US style plugs and outlets. Yes, people would accidentally blow up electrical gear from the US all the time. Not as bad now that most power adapters are 100V to 240VAC.

Comment: @Vince Patron probably not a surge protector, it was the cheapest thing I got (it was a long time ago), and it just says "relocatable power tap". Still not sure what is the worst outcome I may get if I will use it...

Comment: @Andy aka if "the car" here is just this thing, then I would totally risk it. But if it's also all my devices, and my house fire safety, then totally I would not do that

Comment: It's really up to you. There could be arcing in some very corner cases like at high humidity with voltage glitches. That said, I do it all the time. When I travel overseas I use my homemade compact power strip with 8 outlets. I use one foreign plug adapter and I get 8 U.S. style outlets. Of course, I have to be sure my stuff runs at 220V. Also for safety it has a plug that has a built in 6 Amp fuse (power cord cut from an Ikea light) so I only use it for light loads (phone and laptop chargers, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have pictured is a "socket strip". It has six sockets connected to the mains plug via a switch. It may also have an indicator light.

It neither converts voltage or frequency. The wires connect straight through.

> Will it cause any problems if I just plug it in the 230V/50Hz outlet to power 230V/50Hz devices?

It is not designed for 230 V.

> What output frequency and voltage will I get?

Whatever you connect it to.

> Also, how to calculate max. load/wattage for it, considering it will be used with 230V, and not with 125V, will it be lower?

Why would you even want to do this? No 230 V plugs will fit into the sockets.

---

> I need such thing, and I have it lying around, but it is made for 120V.

That probably means the insulation between wires and pins on the sockets is only rated for 120 V.

> I have some 100-240V devices with proper plugs, and I have proper plug adapter — it would be enough if it worked correctly with 230V/50Hz. So you are saying that I can not use it with 230V/50Hz?

Apart from the problems above there is the danger that someone will plug a 110 V only device into your plugboard and destroy the device.

The correct solution is:

- Calculate the maximum W (watts) or VA (volt-amps) of all the devices you will have on simultaneously. (There is a technical difference between watts and volt-amps that you don't need to concern yourself with.)
- Purchase a 230 / 115 V transformer with a VA rating that meets or exceeds the number calculated above.

Comment: I need such thing, and I have it lying around, but it is made for 120V. I have some 100-240V devices with proper plugs, and I have proper plug adapter — it would be enough if it worked correctly with 230V/50Hz. So you are saying that I can not use it with 230V/50Hz?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Okay, I assume I should get 230V socket strip then... Will be far cheaper. And what worst-case scenario is possible with such use-case (excluding possible 110 V only devices damage)?

Comment: @Andrey Worst case? The power strip arcs over internally and catches fire in the middle of the night, and you and your family die of smoke inhalation as your house burns to the ground. (You did ask for the worst case, after all.)